# Какой формат у nginx.conf?

Tags: nginx, intellij-idea, pycharm, формат

Работаю с файлами конфигурации nginx. Они имеют формат, который мне ранее не встречался: что-то похожее на смесь `.ini` и JSON:

```
user       www www;  ## Default: nobody
worker_processes  5;  ## Default: 1
error_log  logs/error.log;
pid        logs/nginx.pid;
worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;

events {
  worker_connections  4096;  ## Default: 1024
}
```

Хочу привязать к этим файлам какой-то конкретный формат в среде разработки (PyCharm), чтобы получить подсветку синтаксиса, автоформат и прочие плюшки.

**Вопрос: а как этот формат вообще называется?** У него есть какая-нибудь спецификация?

Предположил, что это так и называется - [configuration file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_file). Но там нет ни слова про блоки в фигурных скобках.

Comment: У nginx свой собственный формат конфигурационного файла. Для форматирования (выравнять скобочки) можно форматерами JavaScript воспользоваться.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Так можно просто взять готовый плагин https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4415. Подсветка синтаксиса там есть

> Configuration file syntax highlighting, auto-completion and inspections.

Comment: Да, я его нашёл, но пока борюсь с ошибками при установке. )

Answer (score 3):

К сожалению, никак не называется.
Формат конфигов был сделан разработчиками nginx для nginx.
СМ: [Аналогичный вопрос на EnSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936260/what-language-are-nginx-conf-files)